# I'm looking to do my senior capstone project in the field of medical tomography, what is a good book to get acquainted with the field?

Tags: image-processing, reference-request, 3d

I'm a junior currently pursuing a mathematics degree with aspirations toward medical school. I have a senior project I have my entire last year to devote time to, and I've decided that I want to tackle the challenge of medical signal processing. I'd like to write a program that reconstructs a 3d-model of the object from the cross-sectional images provided to it, very much like a CT scan. However, I have no idea where to start. You can assume that I have a good level of mathematical knowledge or the drive to acquire what is needed, so don't be afraid to throw some academic papers my way! I'd really like to dive in to my research as soon as possible, but I can't quite figure out where to start. What materials would you recommend to someone starting out, such as myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about for a start:

- Buzug, Computed Tomography
- Hermann, Fundamentals of Computerized Tomography

Comment: These books look like exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

An oldie but goodie is Kak and Slaney, Principles of Computerized Tomography which is available on line.

Comment: Awesome, free is great. I'll definitely read this first before I purchase any others.